# Give an example of a linearly independent sequence $[x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots]$ of vectors in $\ell^{\infty}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (x_n) =0$

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

> Give an example of a linearly independent sequence $[x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots]$ of vectors in $\ell^{\infty}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (x_n) =0$.

Solution:

Let $X_n=[x_0,x_1,\dots]$; define $x_0=[-1,0,0,0,\dots]$, $x_1=[0,-1,0,0,\dots]$ and so on.

Let $S_n$ be a partial sums, $S_n=x_0+x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n$. Then $\|S_n\| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ where we defined $\|S_n\|=\sup|S_k|$.

Thank you for your suggestion. :')

Comment: Are you looking for a sequence of elements of $\ell^{\infty}$, right? I think your notation is ambiguous, that's why you are being downvoted. I don't want to edit the question any further (that would be editing the content), so please fix it.

Comment: Your attempted solution is rather obviously wrong: the $k$'th entry in $S_n$ will be $-1$ for $n \ge k$.  Try some $x$'s that will produce some cancellation when you add them.

Comment: Actually $||S_n||=1$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You're missing something here.  It seems that what you wanted to do was define
$$
x_0 = [1,1,1,\dots]
$$
*Then*, define
$$
x_1 = -[1,0,0,\dots]\\
x_2 = -[0,1,0,\dots]
$$
and so forth.  Note, however, that this won't work, since we always have $\|S_n\| = 1$.  On the other hand, we could begin by defining
$$
x_0 = [1,1/2,1/3,\dots]
$$
why does this work any better?

Comment: If I define x1=[-1,0,0,...] ,  x2=[0,-1/2,0,0,...] and so on. Are sequence of vectors linearly independent?

Comment: They are indeed.  What leads you to believe that they are not?

Comment: i'm a little confused haha :)

Comment: If you take the **infinite** sum of the entire sequence, you get zero.  Does this mean that the vectors in the sequence are linearly dependent?